# Degree symbol displayed in Jupyter, but not anywhere else - Python

Tags: python, string, encoding, symbols

I need to print degree symbol (small circle) and everything works great with this code in jupyter notebook:

```
a =  (u'\u00B0')
print a
```

Output : °

But when I run my .py script I got an error: : `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)`

When I use `.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`, or `.encode('utf-8')` there is no error measage, but nothing is printed.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.